# Find the residue(s) of this function at each pole that lies in the contour?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Going through past papers and found this residue question I can't do. The question asks you to find the residue at each pole that lies in the contour shown.

[image]

[image]

I've got [image] as my answer for the poles but can't figure out how to move on from here :S

Comment: You shouldn't get a square root. The equation is $z^5 = -32$.

Comment: ...and you have to get five poles. The question is which ones within the domain's contour?

Comment: What is the value of $R$ in your figure? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poles are at the solutions to $z^5+32=0$, or equivalently, the solutions to $z^5=-32$.

Since $|z|^5 = |z^5| = |-32| = 32$, we have $|z| = 2$. So every pole will be of the form $z = 2\exp {i \theta}$. Then, $z^5 = 2^5\exp \left(5 i\theta\right) = -32,$ or
$$\exp\left(5i\theta\right) = -1.$$

Since $\exp \left(i\pi +2ik\pi\right)= -1$ for integer values of $k$ then $5i\theta = i\pi + 2ik\pi$. Solving this, we get $\theta = \frac{\pi+2k\pi}{5},$ which leads to the unique values of:

$$\theta = \left\{\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{3\pi}{5},\pi,\frac{7\pi}{5},\frac{9\pi}{5}\right\}.$$

If you plot these, it becomes obvious that only the pole at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{5}$ lies within your contour, as long as $R > 2$.

Since this is a simple pole, we can easily evaluate the residue using
$$\textrm{Res}\left(\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}; z=\alpha\right) = \frac{g(\alpha)}{h'(\alpha)},$$

so we get

$$\textrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^5+32}; 2\exp\left(i \frac{\pi}{5}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{5\left(2\exp\left[i\frac{\pi}{5}\right]\right)^4}=\frac{1}{80\exp\left[i\frac{4\pi}{5}\right]}.$$

Simplify this, and you are done.

Comment: Had a few basic arithmetic errors there; fixed now.

Comment: Thank you this makes much more sense now